# Inference / Prediction from frozen model: Obtain value after activation through the graph

Tags: tensorflow, tf.keras

I have a simple frozen tensorflow model (frozen in Keras) that I load and then try to use for prediction. I do this first in python (code below), and then using C and libtensorflow (and get the same results). The examples I have found provide the the logits (before activation) as the final output, rather than the class label after activation. Is there a way to obtain the label through the graph itself?

I understand I can operate the sigmoid / softmax operators on the logits, but that's not what I want to do. (I'm porting the code to use the libtensorflow C api, and would prefer to let the graph do the math.)

My understanding is that the session runs the graph to the operation / tensor, and stops before that operation. Is there a way to get the operation after the activation?

Keras Model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(21,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Tensorflow code to load frozen model and predict:

```
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
with tf.Session() as sess:
    with gfile.FastGFile('slopemodel/slopemodel.pb', 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        sess.graph.as_default()
        g_in = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
    tensor_output = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/dense_2/Sigmoid:0')
    tensor_input = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('import/dense_1_input:0')
    predictions = sess.run(tensor_output, {tensor_input:sample})
    print(predictions)
```

Truncated list of important nodes in the graph:

```
['import/dense_1_input',
 'import/dense_1/kernel',
 'import/dense_1/kernel/read',
 'import/dense_1/bias',
 'import/dense_1/bias/read',
 'import/dense_1/MatMul',
 'import/dense_1/BiasAdd',
 'import/dense_1/Relu',
 'import/dense_2/kernel',
 'import/dense_2/kernel/read',
 'import/dense_2/bias',
 'import/dense_2/bias/read',
 'import/dense_2/MatMul',
 'import/dense_2/BiasAdd',
 'import/dense_2/Sigmoid',
 'import/Adam/iterations',
  .
  .
  .]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you simply need to change the `tensor_output` to the one you want to obtain. Note that you will not receive the labels themselves but a one-hot vector from which you'll need to find the corresponding label yourself.

Comment: I do that in the example code above. However I get a logit and not the output of the sigmoid activation function.

Comment: Yes but you took the sigmoid output instead of the activation. Try import/dense_2:0

Comment: dense_2:0 is not a part of the graph. (See list of tensors in the question).
I tried import/dense_2:0 and get the following error: "The name 'import/dense_2:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'import/dense_2', does not exist in the graph."

Comment: Hm, can you post the source code of the model? There should be an output tensor somewhere beyond the sigmoid node. The list is clearly incomplete.

Comment: Ah I guess I skipped a detail. It was created in Keras and frozen in Keras. I've updated my question with the Keras Model.

Comment: You chose to output sigmoid as activation in this model! You can use the Activation layer to add a final activation with a chosen number of classes.